# Starvation algorithm in operating system

Tags: algorithm, operating-system, critical-section, mutual-exclusion

Is there an algorithm for mutual exclusion with shared flag variables, as the Peterson's one, that doesn't prevent the starvation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course.  Simply alter the resolution strategy for your flags -- when several consumers have to wait for a resource.  Instead of a FIFO queue, use a random selection, or LIFO, or anything that doesn't recognize a long-suffering request's tenure in the request pool.